# How to match only the first line using regex?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have a following html code:

```
<div data-123 style="background-color: green; color: red;">
    <div style="background-color: green;">Hello World <p>Another tag</p></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to match style attribute for which I use this regex:

```
/(style=)("|')(\w.+)("|')/i
```

I only want to match only the first line i.e. if there's no style tag in first line/tag, then it shouldn't match the next line for style tag.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
/\A.*(style=)("|')(\w.+)("|')/i
```

Comment: some observations: `\A` won't work in js, use `^` instead... `"|'` is fine, but usually character class `["']` is used instead of single character alternations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't use RegEx to extract attibutes/elements from string**.

You can use DOM APIs to extract an attribute value.

```js
const str = `<div data-123 style="background-color: green; color: red;">
    <div style="background-color: green;">Hello World <p>Another tag</p></div>
</div>`;

const el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;

const div = el.querySelector('div[data-123]');
console.log(div.getAttribute('style'));
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is due to greedy behavior of regex matching. Try to convert the regex to non-greedy matching. Please check https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy